# orthogonal sequences of random variables independence proof

Tags: probability, correlation

[Question is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHqLM.jpg)

It is independence that wants to be shown, isn't it? In which way should I follow to proof this independence?

Comment: uncorrelated does not imply independence -- see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncorrelated_random_variables#When_uncorrelatedness_implies_independence or here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/85363/simple-examples-of-uncorrelated-but-not-independent-x-and-y -- Anyway you just have to show that the expectations are multiplicative, not necessarily that $X$ and $W$ are independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\E}{\mathbb{E}}$Use linearity of expectation, and the fact that the variables are uncorrelated, to compute this directly: $$\E[ZW]=\E\left[(a_1X_1 +\dots a_kX_k)\cdot(a_{k+1}X_{k+1} + \dots a_n X_n)   \right] \\= \E [a_1a_{k+1}X_1 X_{k+1}+ \dots a_1a_nX_n + a_2a_{k+1}X_2X_{k+1}+\dots+a_ka_nX_kX_n] \\ = a_1a_{k+1}\E[X_1X_{k+1}]+ \dots+ a_ka_n\E[X_kX_n] = 0+\dots0=0, $$ since by assumption $\E[X_iX_j]=0$ whenever $i \not=j$ (and this is the case for all products occurring in $ZW$ because the indices in $Z$ range from $1$ to $k$ and those in $W$ range from $k+1$ to $n$).

Thus the equality $\E[ZW]$ holds as long as $\E[Z]=0$ or $\E[W]=0$ (because then $\E[Z]\E[W]=0$. Do you think you can take it from there?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So that means, to get E[Z]=0 , E[X1]=E[X2]=...=E[Xk]=0  must be like this? and same for E[W].

Comment: @tachy That or (more generally) the expectations of $X_1, \dots, X_k$ could be linearly dependent -- then $E[Z]=0$ even if none of the $E[X_i]=0$, likewise $E[W]=0$ would hold if the expectations of $X_{k+1}, \dots, X_n$ were linearly dependent. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_independence#Definition Do you know what linear dependence is?

Comment: Actually I don't know but I am viewing now the wikipedia page that you posted.

Comment: as it says in question, X1,X2,...Xn are uncorrelated, that means they are linearly dependent?

Comment: @tachy The best way. to solve this I believe would be to expand the expression$E(Z)E(W)$ and use the fact that $A$ and $B$ are uncorrelated if and only if $E(A)E(B)=E(AB)$. I think what I said previously regarding linear dependence is wrong; if you want to be even more confused see the following link http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/174994/set-of-uncorrelated-but-linearly-dependent-variables